# Can't access file in the raw folder

Tags: java, android, file, android-resources

I'm new to Android development. I have a `test.txt` file in the `res\raw` folder. For some reason, I'm not able to access it.

Here's the code I'm using just to test. How come `file.exists()` returns `false`?

```
final String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/raw/test.txt";
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

final File file = new File(uri.getPath());
boolean exists = file.exists(); // Returns false.
```

By the way, I need to get the `Uri` of the file. I need that in order to be able to use an existing function that accepts a `Uri` as an argument.

Comment: Just use `getResources().openRawResource()` to access file ...

Comment: @ADM, I need the `Uri` for the reason I explained in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How come file.exists() returns false?

First, a resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device.

Second, `getPath()` on `Uri` simply returns the path portion of the `Uri`. In your case, that is `/raw/test.txt`. If the `Uri` were the `https` URL of your question, the path would be `/questions/56090894/cant-access-file-in-the-raw-folder`. Neither of those would be valid filesystem paths on any Android device. You cannot take semi-random strings, pass them to the `File` constructor, and expect them to have meaning.

> I need to get the Uri of the file

If you really mean "get a `Uri` for the resource", you are welcome to try your `uri`. The `android.resource` scheme is a bit obscure, and so there is a good chance that the function that you are using will not support it.

In that case, you will need to:

- Open an `InputStream` on your raw resource (`getResources().openRawResource()` on a `Context`)
- Open a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`
- Try `Uri.fromFile()` to create a `Uri` for the library

It is also possible that the function is expecting some other sort of `Uri`. Since we do not know what function this is, we cannot review its documentation (if it has any) and tell you what it may or may not be expecting.

Comment: The function is expecting an `android.net.Uri`. Also, can you elaborate on this?

"First, a resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device." When you add a resource to your `res` folder it should be available on the device. What's the point of the `res` folder, otherwise?

Comment: @ataravati: "The function is expecting an android.net.Uri" -- but more likely it is expecting only a subset of the infinite number of possible `Uri` schemes. For example, if you use `Uri.parse("ataravati://do/you/think/that/your/function/will/handle.this")`, most likely your function will have problems using that `Uri` for anything other than printing it out. "When you add a resource to your res folder it should be available on the device" -- it is. It is just not a file on the device. It is an entry in the app's APK, nothing more.

Comment: then, how do I get the Uri from a resource file. This should be a very simple task. There's no other way than using an InputStream? That sounds too complicated for such a trivial thing.

Comment: @ataravati: I cover this in my answer. You can try your `android.resource` `Uri`, and if that does not work, you can copy the content of the resource to a file and try a `Uri` for that. But if the function is expecting an `http` or `https` or `content` or `ftp` or some other scheme, and not `android.resource` or `file`, neither of those approaches will work. Hopefully, this function has documentation that tells you want it needs. If not, ask the developer who wrote the function what it needs. Simply "The function is expecting an android.net.Uri" is insufficient.